# Delphi Chromium Embedded Framework 3 and Voice Recognition

Tags: delphi, chromium, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to integrate something like this:

http://ctrlq.org/dictation/

in my Delphi application (I'm using XE3).

I'm using DCEF3 to get the chrome embedded voice recognition but I can't get the microphone permissions. It basically doesn't ask for them.

Anyone knows if this is possible?